# How can i stop a launched script programmatically?

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I use **ProcessBuilder** Class to  launch  a dos script which did an infinite ping.

How can i stop the script programmatically because  **Destroy**()  function  stops  the process not  the script ?

PS: Doing another process to  kill the process launched isn't the  best solution.

Sorry for the  bad formulation.

Comment: On a Unix system, I would suggest to run "ps" and search the pid of script process to kill it. Alternatively - could you change your script? To run forever ... or until some marker file is created, for example.

Comment: I've said  a  dos script,  so the  system is windows (MS-DOS)  not  unix,  
thank you  for  your  answer.